# How to get Blob Metadata in Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to know how to get Blob content along with metadata in Azure function. I am using Event Grid as a trigger and Blob Storage Input binding. Of course, I can get blob content but not metadata.
I want this done using Node.js.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling getBlobMetadata(container, blob [, options], callback) method on your Blob Service? More info here:
http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#getBlobMetadata__anchor